# Computer won't parse JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, maps

So I have been working on a project that should allow the user to import a JSON file into a Google Map. I made a function "loaded()" that parses the imported file so that it can be cycled through. It works 100% on my laptop, but whenever I run the same exact program on the same web browser (chrome), it is unable to parse the imported string which causes the program to crash and not draw anything on the map.

```
function importJSON(){
                var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
                reader.onload = loaded;
            }

            function loaded(evt) {
                alert("File Loaded Successfully");
                var fileString = evt.target.result;
                $("#feed").text(fileString);

                var locationData = JSON.parse(fileString);


                //Test alert**
                //alert(locationData.locations[4].name);

                for(var i=0; i<=locationData.locations.length; i++){
                    var data = locationData.locations[i];

                    if(data.type=="marker"){

                        var locationLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

                        //Creates marker and sets it on the map
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: locationLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            editable: true,
                            draggable: true

                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                    }

                    else if(data.type=="rec"){
                        alert("rectangle");
                    }
                }
            }
```

If anyone knows what could be the issue, I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Edit: ** I have already verified that my JSON file is the correct format but I'll post it below. The error that I get in Google Chrome's debugger is "Uncaught syntax error unexpected number". From what I can tell, the line that's causing the problems is "var locationData = JSON.parse(fileString);"

```
{
"locations": [
    {
        "id": "ce",
        "type": "marker",
        "name": "Centennial East (CE)",
        "lat": 40.50705,
        "lng": -88.98982
    },
    {
        "id": "sfhb",
        "type": "rec",
        "name": "State Farm Hall of Business (SFHB)",
        "lat": 40.50715,
        "lng": -88.99214
    }
]
```

}

Comment: but what is the error? and is `FileReader` actually trying to read a file from the disk??

Comment: Well that's awesome. Did you verify the [JSON was valid](http://jsonlint.com/)? What is the error message you're getting? Please post a sample of your JSON.

Comment: I have already verified that my JSON file is the correct format but I'll post it below. The error that I get in Google Chrome's debugger is "Uncaught syntax error unexpected number". From what I can tell, the line that's causing the problems is "var locationData = JSON.parse(fileString);"